# Exporting 3D asset from Autodesk Maya to Adobe Aero: colours disapear?

Tags: 3d, maya, export

The colours disapear from my asset when I export it from Maya and try to import it to Adobe Aero. Why?

Comment: Can you walk us through how to create a simple example asset that shows this problem, what export settings you're using, what file format, and how you're doing the import?

Comment: I used the .obj file format and I import it via the iPhone Adobe aero app!

Comment: That's 2 of the 4 things I asked you for. Please **edit your question** so it includes all of these details.